# Sylius: How to sort product by variant.sku

Tags: sylius

I would like to sort the products by its sku. How would that be possible ?
I tried to add in ProductRepository.php:

```
...
$queryBuilder = $this->getCollectionQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder
        ->innerJoin('product.taxons', 'taxon')
        ->innerJoin('product.variants', 'variant')
        ->andWhere('taxon = :taxon')
        ->setParameter('taxon', $taxon)
    ;

    foreach ($criteria as $attributeName => $value) {
        $queryBuilder
            ->andWhere('product.'.$attributeName.' IN (:'.$attributeName.')')
            ->setParameter($attributeName, $value)
        ;
    }
    $queryBuilder->orderBy('variant.sku');
...
```

but got:

> Cannot select distinct identifiers from query with LIMIT and ORDER BY
>   on a column from a fetch joined to-many association. Use output
>   walkers.

Answer (score 1):

Finally what I did: Sorted the products just before output in a [custom twig function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters):

*macros.html.twig*

```
{% set products = skusort(products) %}
```

In my *SkusortExtenstion.php* (as of PHP 5.3)

```
$product->getIterator()->uasort(function($a, $b){
         return $a->getMasterVariant()->getSku() > $b->getMasterVariant()->getSku(); 
    });
return $product;
```

Was afraid of performance issue as there's a lot of products but seems to be very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to reload method getPaginator() of class Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository. In that case we must instantinate DoctrineORMAdapter with $useOutputWalkers flag (the latest constructor argument).

So, put the folowing code in your ProductRepository.php:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getPaginator(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder)
{
    return new Pagerfanta(new DoctrineORMAdapter($queryBuilder, true, true));
}
```